# Are there some Linked data websites use distributed sparql Endpoints and provide cross-domain data search services?

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data, linked-data-platform

Is there a website x:

- Searching rdf resources from distributed sparql Endpoints.
- Rdf resources come from multiple subject areas and are related .
- Provide some semantic services such as QA, route search ...

I found that:

- 'https://lod-cloud.net/' didn't provide data content search(Searching resources from distributed sparql Endpoints.) .
- 'http://linkedlifedata.com/' puts all the data into the same sparql endpoint and separates it with a graph .

Comment: what is "data content search" in the context of a SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: "data content search" means "search resources from distributed sparql Endpoints"

Comment: and what means "search" - I mean, that is not specific enough. By label? A string occurring in a label? Or what? RDF is a set of triples which are made of RDF terms being URIs, blank nodes or literals. So in which of those do you want to search? And no, I'm not aware of any explicit fulltext index, there were some services which have been shutdown time some ago. If you find some SPARQL endpoint it might provide fulltext search via custom SPARQL function.

Comment: Indeed you could start creating and hosting such a service by yourself, I don't think there is much funding today for public services like that, that's why there is no such one. It's expensive, it has to be maintained, being updated, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I didn't make it clear.

I'm referring to "search" that can embody "Linked Data" characteristics, such as QA, route search, or other semantic services.

What's the point of turning data into RDF if we don't do semantic services?

Comment: I'm very excited about the future of the Semantic Web, and I wonder if there are websites that already offer Semantic Web services, since there are many things that can be done without RDF.

Is my understanding wrong? I wish I could get some advice.